# React const render method syntax for propTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Syntax question... I'm trying to figure out where to set proptypes in the newer React const render method.

In this const, where would I place the propTypes: {...} block?

```
const PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay = () => (

  <div className="playlist-album-info-overlay">
    <h2>Album Title</h2>
    <p className="album-kind">Private</p>
  </div>
);

export default PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to how you attach `propTypes` to a `class` not using the ES7 class property syntax ([*stage 1 proposal*](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties)), you can attach them as a property of the arrow function:

```
const PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay = () => (
  <div className="playlist-album-info-overlay">
    <h2>Album Title</h2>
    <p className="album-kind">Private</p>
  </div>
);

PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay.propTypes = {
  // ...
};

export default PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) says:

> They are pure functional transforms of their input, with zero
>   boilerplate. However, you may still specify .propTypes and
>   .defaultProps by setting them as properties on the function...

So you should be able to do this:

```
const PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay = () => (

  <div className="playlist-album-info-overlay">
    <h2>Album Title</h2>
    <p className="album-kind">Private</p>
  </div>
);

PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay.propTypes = {
     text: React.PropTypes.string  //example
}

export default PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay;
```